# Orthogonal diagonalization of Symmetic Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Step 1: find the symmetric matrix A which represents q and find its characteristic polynomial \Delta (t).
Step 2: find the eigenvalues of A which are the roots of \Delta (t).
Step 3: for each eigenvalues \lambda of A in step 2, find an orthogonal basis of its eigenspace.
Step 4: normalize all eigenvectors in step 3 which then form an orthonormal basis of Rn.
Step 5: let P be the matrix whose columns are the normalized eigenvectors in step 4.

I don't understand how to find the orthogonal basis of the eigenspace once I have the eigenvalues. I know how to compute the characteristic polynomial and obtain the eigenvalues. I would appreciate if someone could provide step-by-step detailed explanation for steps 3 and 4. I tried doing it on my own with some other examples that have the values given and I obtain different values.

Comment: Use Gram-Schmidt

Comment: Solve $(A-\lambda v) = 0$ for each eigenvalue $\lambda$. For distinct eigenvalues the resulting vectors $v$ are guaranteed to be orthogonal. When an eigenvalue is duplicated, the solution space is for instance a plane, in which you need to select 2 orthogonal vectors.

Comment: I solve with (lambda V - A) for each eigenvalue lambda. e.g. for this matrix ({1,0,0}.{0,0,1},{0,1,0}) I found that there are three eigenvalues lambda1 =1 lambda2 = 1 and lambda2 = -1. Now I don't know how to find the eigenvectors that will form the columns of matrix P. I'd appreciate if someone could provide an explanation on how to do it. Most videos say we can see and just provide the answers but not the way to obtain them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an example, let's pick your matrix:
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&0&1\\0&1&0\end{bmatrix}$$
To find the eigenvectors for $\lambda=1$, we need to solve $A-\lambda I=0$, which is:
$$\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0\\0&-1&1\\0&1&-1\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$$
Reducing to row-echelon form gives:
$$\begin{bmatrix}0&1&-1\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$$

For the first solution, we pick $x=1,y=0$, meaning $z=0$.

For the second solution, we pick $x=0,y=1$, so that $z=1$.

So we have the 2 eigenvectors $(1,0,0)$ and $(0,1,1)$.

The Gram-Schmidt procedure can orthonormalize them, which is trivial in this case.

---

**Edit**: To clarify, the first line in the row-echelon form actually means:
$$0\cdot x + 1\cdot y -1 \cdot z \quad = \quad y - z \quad = \quad 0$$
From this we get that we can pick any value for $x$, but whichever value we pick for $y$, it will have to be equal to $z$. So the solution has the general form:
$$(x,y,y)$$
where both $x$ and $y$ can be chosen freely. This solution also satisfies the 2nd and 3rd line in the row-echelon form.

We can rewrite this to the form:
$$x(1,0,0) + y(0,1,1)$$
which shows that there are indeed 2 independent eigenvectors.

Comment: That was exactly my question. I know how to reduce them to row-echelon form, but how and why did you pick those two eigenvectors. That's the part, that seems obvious for most but I don't understand. And why are there two solutions and not only one?

Comment: @user150107: I have added a more extensive explanation in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you know that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of the matrix $A$. By definition, the corresponding eigenspace is $U_\lambda=\{v\in V|Av=\lambda v\}$. Writing $v=(v_1,\ldots,v_n)$, the equation $Av=\lambda v$ becomes a system of $n$ linear equations in $n$ variables. The fact that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ implies that the space of solutions of this system is not trivial. Write down the equations explicitly, and solve the system, i.e. find a basis of the space of solutions, $U_\lambda$ (at this point, it just needs to be any basis). Having done that, use the Gram-Schmidt algorithm to obtain an orthonormal basis.

Answer (score 0):

The definition: $Av=\lambda v$ this means that ($I$ is the identity matrix)
$$Av-\lambda v =0$$
$$(A-\lambda I)v=0$$
So solve the system of equations
$$(A-\lambda I)v = 0$$
and find the solutions - these are the eigenvectors, $v$.

Show that $\lambda=5$ is an eigenvalue of $A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\4&3 \end{bmatrix}$ and determine the eigenspace of $\lambda=5$.\

Setting this up, we have:
$$Ax = 5x.$$
What we want to do is move both terms to one side and factor out the vector $x$. In order to do this, we must use an identity matrix, otherwise the equation wouldn't make sense (we'd be subtracting a constant from a matrix). 
$$
Ax-5x = 0$$
$$(A-5I)x = 0$$
$$ \left(\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\4&3 \end{bmatrix} - \begin{bmatrix} 5 & 0 \\ 0 & 5 \end{bmatrix}\right) \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\0 \end{bmatrix} $$
$$
\begin{bmatrix} -4 & 2\\ 4 & -2 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\0 \end{bmatrix} 
$$

Clearly, the matrix $A-\lambda I$ is singular (i.e. does not have linearly independent rows/columns). This will always be the case by the definition $Ax=\lambda x$, and is often used as an alternative definition.\
In order to solve this homogeneous system of equations, we use Gaussian elimination:
$$\begin{bmatrix} -4 & 2 & 0 \\4 & -2 & 0 \end{bmatrix}\longrightarrow\begin{bmatrix} 1 & -\frac{1}{2} & 0 \\0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$
This implies that any vector $x$ for which $x_1-\frac{1}{2}x_2=0$ will satisfy the eigenvector equation. We can pick any such vector, for example $x=\begin{bmatrix} 1\\2\end{bmatrix} $, and say that the eigenspace of $\lambda=5$ is
$$span\left\lbrace\begin{bmatrix} 1\\2 \end{bmatrix} \right\rbrace$$

Comment: I know the equations and I know how to find the eigenvalues but I don't know how to find the eigenvectors, a short example would be helpful.